# SQL Choosing a Primary Policy if it exists or

Tags: sql, select

I want to write a SQL query using CASE to report the policy owner and details of the policy. The goal is to report the policy type of 'HOME' if the policy owner has a policy of that type or report the next available policy if they don't have a home policy. For example, Sally Powel does not have a HOME policy type, so I should report the VEHICLE. In the case of Van Bommel, we should report the HOME Policy Type since he has a policy of that type which is ACTIVE. Grant Holt has neither home nor vehicle, so I should report FLOOD.

```
POLICY  DETAILS
DETAIL_ID POLICY_ID   POLICY_TYPE       DATE_OF_ISSUE       POLICY_STATUS    
2000           1          HOME         05/09/2010          CANCELLED     
2001           2          VEHICLE      02/03/2012          ACTIVE  
2003           3          FLOOD        01/12/2000          ACTIVE
2004           3          HOME         01/12/2009          CANCELLED
2005           2          HOME         03/04/2009          ACTIVE
2006           1          FLOOD        05/09/2010          ACTIVE

POLICY_ID   POLICY_OWNER 
1            GRANT HOLT   
2            SALLY POWELL
3            VAN BOMMEL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with complex `case` logic.  The first `case` is within the `min()` to assign priorities to the policy types.  The second is to undo that and get their names.

```
select pd.policy_owner,
       (case min(case policy_type when 'HOME' then 1 when 'VEHICLE' then 2 else 3 end)
             when 1 then 'HOME'
             when 2 then 'VEHICLE'
             when 3 then 'FLOOD'
        end)
from owners o join
     policydetails pd
     on o.policy_id = pd.policy_id
group by pd.policy_owner;
```